# Cannot get regular expression to work

Tags: regex

Here are my regular expression versions:

```
Version 1: .*/([^/]+)(?:\.(.*))$
Version 2: .*/([^/]+)(?:\.(.*))?$
```

My substitution is

```
 /$1/
```

My test strings are :

```
Test 1: /features-past/nov-dec-2015/living-with-zill.html?wxY
Test 2: /features-past/nov-dec-2015/livig-with-zill
```

Output expected is:

```
/living-with-zill/
```

Version 1 works on Test 1, but not on Test 2 (no match)

Version 2 works on Test 2, but not on Test 1 (no match)

I thought the 0 or 1 regex (?) would match both. How might rewrite this to get Version 1 or 2 to work on Tests 1 and 2?

Thank you.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer that worked best for you. If any. Else, let know what is still an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You had almost got it - just missed making the quantifier **non-greedy** (or reluctant):

```
.*/([^/]+?)(?:\.(.*))?$
```

So with one modification on OP's version 2, the pattern works. Simply add a `?` after the `+` quantifier so that it becomes non-greedy i.e `([^/]+?)` instead of `([^/]+)`. For the first test string this makes sure that the non-greedy part only matches the text before the dot `.` since there is a non-capturing group for the `.` i.e `(?:\.(.*))?`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YzwPmh/1/)

*Test Strings:*

```
Test 1: /features-past/nov-dec-2015/living-with-zill.html?wxY
Test 2: /features-past/nov-dec-2015/livig-with-zill
```

*Output (after substitution with `$1`):*

```
living-with-zill
livig-with-zill
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add `.` to the negated character class and use

```
.*/([^/.]+).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6yxts/1).

**Details**:

- `.*/` - matches any 0+ chars up to the last `/`
- `([^/.]+)` - captures 1+ chars other than `/` and `.`
- `.*` - matches any 0+ chars.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way I found :

```
\d\/([^\.]*)
```

Comment: However, you cannot be sure about the digit: it may be before another subpath and then this will overmatch.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Regex can only be prepared from a pattern present in the presented extract ;) And this one has this pattern... Nothing is sure after all !

Comment: That's a big assumption (preceding digit) and may not hold true for the rest of OP's dataset

Comment: @degant Same thing... If he has a more complex extract, it's up to him to present it. A developer is supposed to find the easiest and cleanest solution given its context. Otherwise, there is no end to probable cases we could think of, and we all know that very well :)

Comment: Yes, that's true :)